Vacuum tube amp RF plate choke design
I am building a vacuum tube RF power amplifier for SSB. Here is the link for the amplifier.
https://www.qsl.net/vu2awc/ham_radio_india_v/vu2atn_qro/vu2atn.htm
I need to clarify first that I am building for 100 watt RF power approx. I want to operate 14,21,24,28 MHz bands.
Almost all the forums I have seen, when talk about vacuum tube based amplifier, all are at the KW level.
All the calculations, assumptions, suggestions are for kilowatt level RF power amplifier. So I could not get anything
for my build. Ultimately I started this thread.
My question is how to make a plate choke, that goes between DC power supply and anode.
There is a reference here
https://www.w8ji.com/rf_plate_choke.htm
But I cannot understand it properly. Appears that lots of analysis required.
How many turns of what size copper wire needed to make it. Assuming 750V supply and max 250mA. For coil former I do not have ceramic tube or any exotic material like fiber glass tube or Teflon tube. I have 2 options as coil former:

A high quality thick walled glass test tube approx 150mm long and 25mm in diameter
Delrin rod 16 or 22 mm in dia 150mm long.

Please help me on this.

Well, it specifies 2.5mH. Do you need one of such value and free of series resonance below 30MHz?

yes. i will follow the circuit design
